# Can I have for(i=0;i<size;i++){"item"+i = ...}?

Tags: java

I want to achieve this:

```
int item1, item2, item3;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  "item"+i = i;
}
```

How would I do this? I want to get the variable name there but it would be a combination of something that doesn't work (string+integer) instead of the variable name

Comment: Java is both statically typed and has static variable names.  Short answer: NO, you can not do that.

Comment: arrays are your friend!

Comment: Arrays are the best option, but if you're using individual fields which have already been created (no dynamic creation in Java) you can check out [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html). Kind of ambitious and unnecessary for this purpose, though.

Answer (score 7):

You need an array for this, instead of various similarly named variables.

```
int[] item = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    item[i] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to rgettman's answer, you could also use a `Map` to stick with your strings.

```
Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(int i = 0;i < 3;i ++){
    data.put("item" + i, i);
}
```

Although this may be a tad overkill.

As per Flight Odyssey's comment, you can then retrieve data with:

```
data.get("item"+i).intValue();
```

Although the .intValue() is optional in some cases due to unboxing.

Comment: You can then retrieve data from the map with `data.get("item"+i).intValue();`

Comment: @FlightOdyssey Added that to my answer and credited :)